# How to convert a CD into MP3 files with just Windows XP & Windows Media Player 9?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, mp3, windows-media-player, compact-disc

How can I convert a CD into MP3 files with Windows XP and Windows Media Player 9?

At first sight it seems it can only save WMA files.

Comment: I think we need a bit more information here. Why only those two items. Why not install iTunes or another program more suitable for MP3 encoding, that has built in codecs and capability?

Comment: @Paperlantern: 1) too much work 2) i'd like to have a simple recipe that works on every machine "out of the box".

Comment: @Paperlantern, is there any simple solution like upgrading the WMP?

Comment: why the downvote? If the answer sounds "it's not possible", is that an automatic reason for downvote? I don't think so.

Comment: [WMP10](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20426) Has this ability, but not WMP9.

Comment: As for the downvote, it wasn't me, but I think people like to see a little more effort in the question. Yours was very direct yes, but like I said, a little more backstory and reasoning would have been helpful.

Comment: *"little more effort in the question"*? why should I question 1000 characters long if it can be expressed with one simple sentence? Its saving people's time. Or does somebody get irritated just because the question is 100% clear from the title itself?

Comment: @Tomas No, the thing is: The downvote button says "This question […] does not show research effort". It should show that you've genuinely tried to research for answers before asking. As for the title, it's best to put the main question into the question's body again, even if it's a bit redundant. Your question might even trigger a low quality filter if it's too short.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple solution: just **install an mp3 codec for Windows Media Player**! Works for WMP 9! **No new software needed.**

http://download.cnet.com/mp3-codec-for-Windows-Media-Player/3000-2169_4-10630559.html

Comment: Oh ok. I guess we we're all half right then! Half points all around! (Or 1/3)

Comment: well @skub, but your part of the answer is rather obvious :-P

Comment: Technically, this MP3 codec *is* "new software".

Comment: @Tomas You asked it... haha

Answer (score 12):

There isn't a solution out of the box, since WMP version 9  doesn't ship with the MP3 encoder out of the box (later versions do).

No matter what you do, you'll need to install something in order to get this to work for you.

My suggestion is to install a program like [CDex](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net/) which runs on Windows XP, is straight forward to use and powerful if you need more encoding options later.

Comment: thanks for the tip for CDex, but I prefer not to install new programs...

Answer (score 7):

As of version 8, Windows Media Player contains a MP3 CBR encoder (`l3codec?.acm`); however, this must be enabled manually in earlier versions by editing the registry.

You can do this through `regedit.exe`; the key name is `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Settings\MP3Encoding` in which you have to add four REG_DWORD values, each representing a position in the "Quality" slider: `LowRate`, `MediumRate`, `MediumHighRate` and `HighRate`. The data has to be in *bps*; for example, `0x1f400` (hex) or `128000` (dec) for 128 kbps.

The following `.reg` file, when imported, will enable 128/192/256/320 kbps:

```
Windows Registry Editor 5.0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Settings\MP3Encoding]
"LowRate"=dword:0001f400
"MediumRate"=dword:0002ee00
"MediumHighRate"=dword:0003e800
"HighRate"=dword:0004e200
```

This appears to be enabled by default on my system (Windows XP with WMP 11).

However, [some sources](http://www.sagebrush.com/mp3tech.htm) claim that the `l3codeca.acm` codec, used by earlier versions (up to v10), is rather limited in features – for example, 22050 Hz sample rate. (I could not verify this myself.) WMP 11 includes `l3codecp.acm`, which does not appear to have such limitations. Since you are using Windows XP, you can (and probably *should*) upgrade to WMP 11.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure if WMP 9 will rip to MP3. I know 10 will and I'm certain 12 will since I just took the screenshot in 12.

Go to the menu Tools - > Options. Then select the "Rip Music" tab. Under "Rip Settings" select MP3 from the "Format" drop down menu.

[image]

Comment: of course I tried this, it doesn't show the "mp3" possibility. But it does after installing the codec (see my answer)